pyside6 qvirtualkeyboard not clickable
I have the following minimal example with a button that triggers a dialog with a text area. The virtualkeyboard is showing up correctly on the screen but the buttons are not clickable
import os
import os
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTextEdit
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout, QDialog, QPushButton



def trigger():
    dlg = QDialog()
    text_edit = QTextEdit()
    layout = QVBoxLayout()
    layout.addWidget(text_edit)
    dlg.setLayout(layout)
    dlg.exec()


os.environ["QT_IM_MODULE"] = "qtvirtualkeyboard"

app = QApplication([])

btn = QPushButton('Trigger')
btn.clicked.connect(lambda: trigger())

window = QMainWindow()
window.setCentralWidget(btn)
window.show()

app.exec()

If I remove the dialog and set the QTextArea directly to the QMainWindow it works just fine. Anyone knows how to get it to work?

Add global dlg and use dlg.open() instead of dlg.exec().

@ekhumoro dlg.open() did the trick, if you write it as an answer I'll tick it off

Opening the dialog with exec will block, so you should use open instead. This may mean you need to keep a reference to the dialog, since open returns immediately.
